# Is every ideal of this form radical?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f,g \in k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ be polynomials over an algebraically closed field $k$, with $g$ irreducible. Is the ideal $I=\langle y f - 1, g \rangle \subseteq k[x_1,\dots, x_n,y]$ radical?

Comment: Did you try to figure out how the quotient ring look like?

Comment: @user26857 Thank you. I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact $I$ is prime. For any prime ideal $P \subseteq k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ (not necessarily a PID) with $f \notin P$, the ideal $\langle y f -1 \rangle + P$ is prime. Indeed, $$k[x_1,\dots, x_n, y] / \langle y f -1 \rangle + P \cong k[x_1,\dots, x_n, 1/f]/ P.$$ Since $P$ is prime in $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$, $P$ is prime in $k[x_1,\dots, x_n,1/f]$, so $k[x_1,\dots, x_n, y] / \langle y f -1 \rangle + P$ is irreducible, i.e. $\langle y f -1 \rangle + P$ is prime.

Comment: The product ideal can't be prime! The sum is another story.

Comment: Oops, thanks again.

Comment: If $f\in P$, then the ideal is not prime. You have to assume that $f\notin P$.